# Can we use "unwind segue" to go back two levels instead of unwinding to root controller?

Tags: ios6

[Flow Chart Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsQVn.jpg)

Hi,

I am newbie in ios development. Is there any possible way to use "Unwind segue" to go to particular view controller instead of going into Root controller.. i have attached the diagram which represents the flow of the controllers. Assume that "View controller 3" contains one Button. If i click the button, i want to view "Table view controllor". When i tried with "Unwind Segue" it is going to "View Controller 1".. because "View Controller 1" is the root container for the application. Can we use "Unwind segue" to go to "Table view controller"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers]          objectAtIndex:yourindex] animated:YES];
```

to go to the desired view controller on the stack